# 15.10 x64 Desktop on Dimension 3100 - X Stability Problems

Tags: xorg, 15.10

It looks like the Xorg/Intel in 15.10 is having problems not writing between the lines (metaphorically speaking) and corrupting memory. Here is the error output, has anyone else run into this.. it gets worse with any blitting.

```
(EE) [mi] EQ overflowing.  Additional events will be discarded until existing ev
ents are processed.
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x4e) [0x55b04a9d062e]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (mieqEnqueue+0x253) [0x55b04a9b2313]
(EE) 2: /usr/bin/X (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x55b04a88c152]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f1aca31d000+0x60a7) [0x7f1a
ca3230a7]
(EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f1aca31d000+0x687d) [0x7f1a
ca32387d]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x55b04a81c000+0x96ac8) [0x55b04a8b2ac8]
(EE) 6: /usr/bin/X (0x55b04a81c000+0xbfc52) [0x55b04a8dbc52]
(EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f1acfa49000+0x352f0) [0x7f1acfa7e2f0
]
(EE) 8: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (ioctl+0x7) [0x7f1acfb460b7]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f1acbe20000+0x2320d) [0x7
f1acbe4320d]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f1acbe20000+0x26ab4) [0x
7f1acbe46ab4]
(EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f1acbe20000+0x5a05d) [0x
7f1acbe7a05d]
(EE) 12: /usr/bin/X (BlockHandler+0x4a) [0x55b04a878c8a]
(EE) 13: /usr/bin/X (WaitForSomething+0x163) [0x55b04a9cd393]
(EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (0x55b04a81c000+0x57fa1) [0x55b04a873fa1]
(EE) 15: /usr/bin/X (0x55b04a81c000+0x5c34b) [0x55b04a87834b]
(EE) 16: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f1acfa69a4
0]
(EE) 17: /usr/bin/X (_start+0x29) [0x55b04a8626c9]
(EE) 
(EE) [mi] These backtraces from mieqEnqueue may point to a culprit higher up the
 stack.
(EE) [mi] mieq is *NOT* the cause.  It is a victim.
(EE) [mi] EQ overflow continuing.  100 events have been dropped.
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x4e) [0x55b04a9d062e]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x55b04a88c152]
(EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f1aca31d000+0x60a7) [0x7f1a
ca3230a7]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f1aca31d000+0x687d) [0x7f1a
ca32387d]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (0x55b04a81c000+0x96ac8) [0x55b04a8b2ac8]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x55b04a81c000+0xbfc52) [0x55b04a8dbc52]
(EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f1acfa49000+0x352f0) [0x7f1acfa7e2f0
]
(EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (ioctl+0x7) [0x7f1acfb460b7]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f1acbe20000+0x2320d) [0x7
f1acbe4320d]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f1acbe20000+0x26ab4) [0x7
f1acbe46ab4]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f1acbe20000+0x5a05d) [0x
7f1acbe7a05d]
(EE) 11: /usr/bin/X (BlockHandler+0x4a) [0x55b04a878c8a]
(EE) 12: /usr/bin/X (WaitForSomething+0x163) [0x55b04a9cd393]
(EE) 13: /usr/bin/X (0x55b04a81c000+0x57fa1) [0x55b04a873fa1]
(EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (0x55b04a81c000+0x5c34b) [0x55b04a87834b]
(EE) 15: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f1acfa69a4
0]
(EE) 16: /usr/bin/X (_start+0x29) [0x55b04a8626c9]
(EE) 
(EE) [mi] EQ overflow continuing.  200 events have been dropped.
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x4e) [0x55b04a9d062e]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x55b04a88c152]
(EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f1aca31d000+0x60a7) [0x7f1a
ca3230a7]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f1aca31d000+0x687d) [0x7f1a
ca32387d]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (0x55b04a81c000+0x96ac8) [0x55b04a8b2ac8]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x55b04a81c000+0xbfc52) [0x55b04a8dbc52]
(EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f1acfa49000+0x352f0) [0x7f1acfa7e2f0
]
(EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (ioctl+0x7) [0x7f1acfb460b7]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f1acbe20000+0x2320d) [0x7
f1acbe4320d]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f1acbe20000+0x26ab4) [0x7
f1acbe46ab4]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f1acbe20000+0x5a05d) [0x
7f1acbe7a05d]
(EE) 11: /usr/bin/X (BlockHandler+0x4a) [0x55b04a878c8a]
(EE) 12: /usr/bin/X (WaitForSomething+0x163) [0x55b04a9cd393]
(EE) 13: /usr/bin/X (0x55b04a81c000+0x57fa1) [0x55b04a873fa1]
(EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (0x55b04a81c000+0x5c34b) [0x55b04a87834b]
(EE) 15: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f1acfa69a4
0]
(EE) 16: /usr/bin/X (_start+0x29) [0x55b04a8626c9]
(EE) 
[  8417.862] [mi] Increasing EQ size to 1024 to prevent dropped events.
[  8417.863] [mi] EQ processing has resumed after 211 dropped events.
[  8417.863] [mi] This may be caused my a misbehaving driver monopolizing the se
rver's resources.
[  8441.885] (EE) intel(0): Failed to submit rendering commands (Input/output er
ror), disabling acceleration.
[  8441.886] (EE) intel(0): When reporting this, please include /sys/class/drm/c
ard0/error and the full dmesg.
[  8491.132] (EE) 
[  8491.133] (EE) Backtrace:
[  8491.133] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x4e) [0x55b04a9d062e]
[  8491.133] (EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x55b04a81c000+0x1b8999) [0x55b04a9d4999]
[  8491.133] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f1acfa49000+0x352f0) [0
x7f1acfa7e2f0]
[  8491.133] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f1acbe20000+
0x1046cb) [0x7f1acbf246cb]
[  8491.133] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f1acbe20000+
0x10749b) [0x7f1acbf2749b]
[  8491.133] (EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (DRI2SwapBuffers+0x1c8) [0x55b04a9a2cf8]
[  8491.133] (EE) 6: /usr/bin/X (0x55b04a81c000+0x18867c) [0x55b04a9a467c]
[  8491.133] (EE) 7: /usr/bin/X (0x55b04a81c000+0x5818f) [0x55b04a87418f]
[  8491.134] (EE) 8: /usr/bin/X (0x55b04a81c000+0x5c34b) [0x55b04a87834b]
[  8491.134] (EE) 9: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0
x7f1acfa69a40]
[  8491.134] (EE) 10: /usr/bin/X (_start+0x29) [0x55b04a8626c9]
[  8491.134] (EE) 
[  8491.134] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x10
[  8491.134] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[  8491.134] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[  8491.134] (EE) 
[  8491.134] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  8491.134] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for ad
ditional information.
[  8491.134] (EE) 
[  8491.160] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[  8491.218] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed upstream:
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92911

The relevant commit message: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92911#c4

The fix was not backported to Wily yet.
See
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1522727 for details.